# Remove trailing slash using .htaccess for a particular page

Tags: .htaccess

I've modified my .htaccess file to force trailing slashes on all the pages but I'm wondering how to remove the trailing slash in a particular url  page? Need help. For example:

abc.com/test successfully redirects to abc.com/test/

But I want to remove that force trailing slash in a particular url of the site,

abc.com/demo/ should redirect to abc.com/demo

Here what I have done so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Update:
To remove trailing slashes for multiple urls what would be the code, eg abc.com/demo2/ abc.com/demo3/ abc.com/demo4/  etc.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^demo/$ /demo [L,R]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: sorry, your code isn't working, and it messed up my trailing slash code as well, no trailing slash url and no trailing slash remove from demo

Comment: @indy This removes a traling from `/demo/` and adds traling slashes to other uris . There is no need to combine your `traling slash code` with this.

Comment: I have used only your code, but nothing is working, site is messed up, all url is redirect to index.php page with a trailing slash eg (https://erfs.com/index.php/) , and css is messed up

Comment: @indy I have updated the rule. Clear your browser cache and then test it.

Comment: I have updated my query and also raised a separate question for this, hope you can help me on this